# Using custom classifier for mutilabel classification with GridSearchCV and OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning, multilabel-classification

I am trying to use the OneVsRestClassifier to do multilabel classification on a set of comments. My objective is to tag each comment to a possible list of topics. My custom classifier uses a manually curated list of words and their corresponding tags in a csv to tag each comment. I am trying to combine the results obtained from the Bag of Words technique and my custom classifier using the VotingClassifier. Here is part of my existing code:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

class CustomClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, word_to_tag):
        self.word_to_tag = word_to_tag

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        prob = np.zeros(shape=(len(self.word_to_tag), 2))

        for index, comment in np.ndenumerate(X):
            prob[index] = [0.5, 0.5]
            for word, label in self.word_to_tag.iteritems():
                if (label == self.class_label) and (comment.find(word) >= 0):
                    prob[index] = [0, 1]
                    break

        return prob

    def _get_label(self, ...):
        # Need to have a way of knowing which label being classified
        # by OneVsRestClassifier (self.class_label)

bow_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=1, max_df=0.9)), 
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False)),
                    ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5)),
                   ])
custom_clf = CustomClassifier(word_to_tag_dict)

ovr_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(VotingClassifier(estimators=[('bow', bow_clf), ('custom', custom_clf)],
                                               voting='soft'))

params = { 'estimator_weights': ([1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]) }
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(ovr_clf, params, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, scoring='precision_samples')

binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()

gs_clf.fit(X, binarizer.fit_transform(y))
```

My intention is to use this manually curated list of words obtained by several heuristics to improve the results obtained by solely applying bag of words. Currently I am struggling to find a way to know which label is being is classified while predicting, since a copy of CustomClassifier is created for each label using OneVsRestClassifier.

Comment: self.class_label seems undefined to me. I'm not sure what you mean by "which label is being classified", Labels are predicted from the data.

Comment: Yes, my question is basically how to determine what the `self.class_label` is? So when OneVsRestClassifier fits the data, it clones the estimator (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/multiclass.py#L73) for each label being classified (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/multiclass.py#L283) if you are doing multilabel classification. So, basically what I need is a way for me to determine which label the cloned CustomClassifier corresponds to when calculating `predict_proba`.

Comment: To describe further, let me give you an example. Lets say the comment is "The food at this restaurant was great. The service at this restaurant was also phenomenal." And let's say that I was working with the labels `["food", "staff", "location", "other", ...]`. Then, OneVsRestClassifier creates a clone of the `VotingClassifier` in this case for each label. This recursively also makes a copy of `CustomClassifier` for each label. But I don't know how I would determine which label the specific instance of `CustomClassifier` corresponds to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `classes_` attribute : http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier

Comment: `ovr_clf.classes_` just seems to be the numpy array of 0 to `n_classes-1` as described by `shape=[n_classes]`. I am looking to determine which label one of the instances of `VotingClassifier` in the `ovr_clf.estimators_` array corresponds to when I am trying to `fit` the data.

Comment: either this array is the answer or I don't understand your question. The first estimator is class 0 vs the rest, the second estimator is class 1 vs the rest. If you named your classes differently, you'd find their names there.

Comment: So, when I try to fit the data on `gs_clf`, the multilabel binarizer converts the `y` labels from `"food", "staff", "location", "other", ...]` to a array of 1s and 0s `[0 1 0 0 ... ]`. So what does the 0 to 15 in the ovr_clf.classes_ correspond to? Does it mean that each the order of the `ovr_clf.estimators_` list is the same as the order of the labels representing the columns in `[0 1 0 0 ...]`? (which basically means its the same as the order as the classes in the `binarizer.classes` list)

Comment: yes. ``classes_`` is what column (in multi-label or in predict_proba) corresponds to which class, for all estimators. For OVR, the ``estimators_`` has the same ordering as ``classes_``.